# Telerik RenderReport

Tags: c#, telerik-reporting

I have some problems with Telerik reports.
Feels like i have missed something...
I wanna create a list of reports, and then write them to ONE file.
But when i write it out i only get one page.
The writer writer over page 1 all foreach, so it just write one page.
But i want several pages... in this case 10.
Have tried write with FileStream, File and more...
Does anyone have a good idea?

```
  public void WriteToFile()
   {
       string path = @"C:\";
       string test = "test";

       var report = new Report2();

       var procceser = new ReportProcessor();


      var list = new List<RenderingResult>();
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       {
           var res = procceser.RenderReport("PDF", report, null);
           list.Add(res);
       }

       string filePath = Path.Combine(path, test);

       var Writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Create(filePath));

       foreach (var renderingResult in list)
       {
           Writer.Write(renderingResult.DocumentBytes);
       }

       Writer.Flush();
       Writer.Close();

   }
```

Comment: i think `var Writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Create(filePath));` will overwrite the file every time so it is doing so.. check [File.Create Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.create.aspx)

Comment: I want to create a new file everytime, but just add more pages to existing file. So that it creates a new every time doesnt matter.

Comment: open the existing file in append mode and then update it.

Comment: Have tried the too, but i only get one page. Its really strange.